# CXF, out interceptor, alter response SOAP body

Tags: java, soap, cxf, interceptor

Using CXF interceptor, I want to alter the response body which is being sent to the client as response. (I want to add some more nodes)
My interceptor is configured as an outgoing interceptor, is being invoked but the body is empty.

```
public class AlterOutBodyInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    private SAAJOutInterceptor saajOut = new SAAJOutInterceptor();

    public AlterOutBodyInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_MARSHAL);
        getBefore().add(SAAJOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        SOAPMessage doc = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
        if (doc == null) {
            saajOut.handleMessage(message);
            doc = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
            // it is executed
        }

        try {
            SOAPBody body = doc.getSOAPBody();
            // here, body doesn't contain anything that the client gets
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing trial-error with getBefore - getAfter and Phases, but without luck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as here:
(we checked cxf sources because it contains a lot of interceptors, we got the ideas from there)

```
public class Interceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    private ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

    public Interceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);
        addBefore(HolderOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        MessageContentsList outObjects = MessageContentsList.getContentsList(message);
        Assert.isTrue(outObjects.size() == 1);
        Object outObject = outObjects.get(0);
        // object is our soap response
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still researching this because at the moment modifications made to body are not sent to the client.